# Compile to WASM On-the-fly

Tags: javascript, compilation, webassembly

Does anyone have a suggestion for a JavaScript tool that will compile a C++ string to Webassembly without having to use command line? Similar to pyodide, but for C++. I am not running node.js, but I can if it is absolutely necessary.